# Check if JSON key value is different than value C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a `JSON` like this :

```
{ 
"content": {
      "shopCart": {
        "numberOfItem": "string",
        "shipCostsAmount": "string"
      },
      "items": {
        [
        {
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemAmount": "200",
          "itemShelf": "string",
        },
        "item2": {
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemAmount": "250",
          "itemShelf": "string",
        },
        "item3": {
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemAmount": "3000",
          "itemShelf": "string",
        }
       ],
      }
   }
}
```

I want to check that the `itemShelf` is different than `Liquor` for example in all the three items.

I can do it for one item like this :

```
public bool CheckItemShelf(Content content)
{
     var itemShelf = content.Items.Item1.itemShelf;
     bool result;
     if ((itemShelf == "Liquor"))
        result = false;
     else
        result = true;
     return result;
}
```

How can I do it for three (or more) items ?

**EDIT :**

Here is the Content class :

```
  public class Content {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets ShopCart
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name="shopCart", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "shopCart")]
    public ShopCart ShopCart { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Items
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name="items", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
    public Items Items { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

I changed the Items into and array, how can i check that all the itemShelf value are not Liquor and have a true or false response ?

Comment: send a string and the item that you want to check to the function instead of the content itself

Comment: Try to use a library to work with JSON data. Something like [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json)

Comment: Thank you, i already use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Why isn't `items` a JSON array? Would make it easier to iterate over.

Comment: @phuzi how to do it ?

Comment: `"items": [
        {
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemAmount": "200",
          "itemShelf": "string",
        },
        {
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemAmount": "250",
          "itemShelf": "string",
        },
        {
          "itemQuantity": "1",
          "itemAmount": "3000",
          "itemShelf": "string",
        }
      ]

Comment: @phuzi , `[JsonProperty("items")]
        public Dictionary<string, Item> Items { get; set; }` and voila.  no need to change the original Json.

Comment: @DragandDrop i have to add it to the Content class ?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XvYPhe .

Comment: The JSON format is written so stupidly.

Comment: @ribaz, not it's not . Dictionary has a uniq key constraint. In order to keep that contraint many choose to serialize to a flat object with key has property name. You can create a  simple test dictionary seriliaze it and see the result.

Comment: @DhonJoe, was the fiddle enought or do I have to craft an answer later? Ps for everyone else you can use the fiddle to create an answer, I don't call shootgun on it. Just be clear on Dictionary part and `.Values` as the key doesn't seems important here.

Comment: @xdtTransform thank you, i edited the question, how can i check that all the itemShelf value are not Liquor and have a true or false response ?

Comment: First, let me state this. Updating an question in a way that invalidate Answer is not ok. 
Second, there is a ton of way to find that. You can search the element with [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) then [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) the result.
You can check if [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) of the element has XYZ, or if [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all) of them do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not very clean but try this:

```
            var gameInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(data);
            var prop = gameInfo.Properties().Children().ToList()[0]["items"].ToArray();

            foreach (var item in prop)
            {
                if (item.Children().ToArray()[0]["itemShelf"].ToString() != "Liquor")
                    continue;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using Linq:

```
var ItemsThatAreNotLiqour = content.Items.Where(item => item.itemShelf != "Liquor");
```

Your classes should like this (i guess this would change your json somehow):

```
public class Item
{
    public string itemQuantity { get; set; }
    public string itemAmount { get; set; }
    public string itemShelf { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public ShopCart shopCart { get; set; }
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think if you change Items from and array to a `Dictionary<string, Item>` you probably won't have to change the json.

Comment: Items is not array, you can't do this.

Comment: @DhonJoe, what is the `Content` class exactly?

Comment: @Andrew It's the content of a Cart

Comment: Right, that was kind of obvious. That's why I said **exactly**, I was expecting some definition. Why can't you iterate over `Items`?

Comment: @Andrew i added the Content class to the question

Comment: I changed the Items into and array, how can i check that all the itemShelf value are not Liquor and have a true or false response ?

Answer (score -3):

My suggestion is to JS to convert item1, item2, item3 into array items

```
let items = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    items.push(content.items['item' + i]);
}
```

You can use LinQ in C#

```
bool anyLiquor = content.Items.Any(x => x.itemShelf == "Linquor");
```

Comment: why JS ? this is about c#

Comment: Because you need to convert to array of item to use LinQ. Pls look at the JSON